# FPS lowering issue while using Cocos2D Particle Effects in CCTouchesMoved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

This is the code I have been using in CCTouchesMoved for producing Particle Effects in the touching locations. But while using this FPS is dropping to 20 while touches is moving! I have tried lowering the life and duration of particles (you can see that in code).....

How can I fix that FPS lowering issue on touches moved while using particle effects???

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{   
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    swipeEffect = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"comet.plist"];

    //Setting some parameters for the effect
    swipeEffect.position = ccp(location.x, location.y);

    //For fixing the FPS issue I deliberately lowered the life & duration
    swipeEffect.life =0.0000000001;
    swipeEffect.duration = 0.0000000001;

    //Adding and removing after effects
    [self addChild:swipeEffect];
    swipeEffect.autoRemoveOnFinish=YES;
}
```

Please help me out... I tried with different particles & minimizing the life and duration, but didn't work! 
Any new ideas for that ? or fixes for what I have done?

Comment: are you using simulator?

Comment: @xuanweng-> I tried both simulator & device. works the same. FPS showing around 20 while touches moved. Applicationd DID NOT Crash, but FPS lowered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly suspect the reason for the slowdown is because you are instantiating a new CCParticleSystemQuad every time the touch moves. Why not just instantiate it once in the `init` or `ccTouchesBegan` method but only set the position and emissionRate in ccTouchesMoved:

```
- (id)init {
   ...

   swipeEffect = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"comet.plist"];
   swipeEffect.emissionRate = 0;
   [self addChild:swipeEffect];

   ...
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   swipeEffect.emissionRate = 10;
}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
   location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
   swipeEffect.position = location;
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   swipeEffect.emissionRate = 0;
}
```

Comment: wow! yea! you are right! now it working so smooth! fps not even going below 55!!! Thanks a bunch! thank you... it is really a nice help.... :)

Comment: also while I tried to increase the emissionRate above 2000 (just out of curiosity & for more visual effect, no urgent need of mine indeed!) fps lowered a bit around 35-40. Is there any other way to fix that too? (not urgent indeed!)

Comment: I think that's like already hitting the limit for iPhone 4 ... maybe you need to be content with 35-40 fps, or just wait for iPhone 5 :P

Comment: owh wait, a better suggestion is to use `CCParticleSystemPoint` .. although maybe the quality will be lowered a bit ..

Comment: @Lukman-> nice suggestions... these are going to help me a lot... thanks again... :) now it's fixed. it worked well..thanks... :)